# Overloaded -> and *: how to access initial class?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a class `Property` containing a data of type `Matrix` and which overloads operators `->`, `*` and `&`, `Matrix` being another class of mine. The overloads give direct access to the data, e.g.

```
Property myProp;
myProp->trace();
```

The above code allows to compute the trace of the matrix directly from the `Property` containing it and without having to first get the data: handy.

Now I want to add a callback to my `Property` which is called when the `Property` gets updated. To do so I would like to be able to write something like:

```
myProp->registerCallback(myCallback);
```

My problem is that `operator->` returns a reference to the `Matrix`, hence `registerCallback` gets called on the matrix class, not on `Property`. As I also overloaded the other operators `*` and `&`, it seems I am no longer able to call a member functions from `Property`.

Hence my question: is there any trick to work with the basic type after an operator was overloaded to return another type?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The overloading the unary operator& is one of those clever tricks that can do more harm than good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should still be able to call functions in `Property` with the `.` operator...

```
Property myProp;
myProp->trace();
myProp.registerCallback(myCallback);
```

You've got a minor misunderstanding. If you overload `operator*` and `operator->` then you object is trying to work like a pointer. This situation comes up often with iterators. An iterator's methods are called with `.` like this.

I have no idea why you would want to overload `operator&`; to achieve the same thing as  fasked's `operator&`, just use `&(*myProp)`. Besides, `&myProp` should give you the address of `myProp`, not its contained object.

Comment: Hum hum... This is so simple that it is embarrassing ;) Thanks anyways!

Comment: That's okay. It's part of getting used to this stuff.

Answer (score 3):

In C++11 there is `std::addressof` function. Also boost library provides `addressof` function.
Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Data
{
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "Data::foo" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class Property
{
public:
    Property() : data(new T) {}
    ~Property() { delete data; }

    T** operator &() {
        return &data;
    }

    T* operator->() {
        return data;
    }

    void foo() {
        std::cout << "Property::foo" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    T *data;
};

int main()
{
    Property<Data> p;

    p->foo();
    std::addressof(p)->foo();
}
```